# BitBucket Compare Branches using REST API

Tags: git, rest, curl, compare, bitbucket

I am working on a java utility to create pull requests from code, instead of using the webpage.

Before creating a pull request, I would like to compare the branches between which I want to create a pull request, compare the branches for differences, identify any merge issues.

I am looking for the REST endpoint that will allow me the compare the branches when I know the branch names without having to determine their last commit ids and also how to identify merge issues from the output.

If there is a cURL way to do this, that will also work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Diff API](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/diff/%7Bspec%7D) as following :

```
GET https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{workspace}/{repo_slug}/diff/{spec}
```

Example :

https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/osrf/sdformat/diff/default..4_to_5

From the official documentation :

> Produces a raw, git-style diff for either a single commit (diffed
>   against its first parent), or a revspec of 2 commits (e.g.
>   3a8b42..9ff173 where the first commit represents the source and the
>   second commit the destination). In case of the latter (diffing a
>   revspec), a 3-way diff, or merge diff, is computed. This shows the
>   changes introduced by the left branch (3a8b42 in our example) as
>   compared againt the right branch (9ff173). This is equivalent to
>   merging the left branch into the right branch and then computing the
>   diff of the merge commit against its first parent (the right branch).
>   This follows the same behavior as pull requests that also show this
>   style of 3-way, or merge diff.

It works for comparing commits, tags and branches

Comment: I will take a look at this and I will also try to find it, but do you know, if this is available with BB API version 1.0?  We are using the 1.0.   Thanks

Comment: @adbdkb I've found [this](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.7.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idm45568366502032) for v1